# Statically linking boost program_options

Tags: c++, boost, linker, boost-program-options

One of the few Boost libraries that are not header only (therefore need to be compiled separately) is program_options.

I need to run a program that I compile on my PC in a cluster that has no Boost installed.
I don't have administrative rights to install Boost and contacting the cluster's admin is too burocractic and slow.

How can I compile my program in my PC (which has Boost) such that it includes program_options (I think this is called static linking)?

Now, I plan to run several instances of my program. Is static linking the best approach? Every instance of my program will load a separate instance of program_options, which is wasteful. Is there a better alternative? Some sort of "local dynamic linking" that I can setup on the cluster without root access?

Comment: what operating system are you using on your PC? Is it the same as the cluster you plan to use?

Comment: @SamMiller No. My PC has Ubuntu. The cluster is OpenSuSE

Answer (score 1):

You can compile and install Boost, or just Boost Options, as a local user. Then compile your program against this local version. Finally, run your code with an updated LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable that includes where the Boost Options library lives.